# Как трактовать тест Shapiro-Wilk?

Tags: python, статистика

У меня есть набор данных и я хочу проверить его на нормальность. Для проверки я использую `stats.shapiro`

```
from scipy import stats
data = .. мои данные

stats.shapiro(data)
```

В результате получаю:

```
(0.9546933174133301, 0.0)
```

Меня смущает, что p-value = 0.
Могу лил я на основе этого сказать, что о моих данных нельзя сказать, что они распределены нормально?

Comment: Покажите как минимум три знака после запятой в значении p.

Comment: Это весь вывод, который у меня есть

Comment: Попробуйте вывод отформить вот примерно так 
   stat, p = stats.shapiro(data)    
   print('Statistics=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))